# Can anyone suggest what to use to make the UI screen as Mention?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uicollectionview, uikit, uipagecontrol

I have design the UI for the below screen as I am little bit confuse that what should have to use for the below screen. As you seen the on the screen below things:

[image]

1.Scrolling part of Images swap.

2.Again another Scrolling images Swap.

So here for the scrolling Images what should I use its `Collection View` for both or `Pagecontrol` for one and `Collection view` for other. Please suggest me.

Thanks and Appreciate for the help...

Comment: Use firstimage that left and right pagecontrol its easy to handle and for next things kitty pretty george use collectionview your problem solve

Comment: But how to swap the images using the page control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UITableView` and in its cell use `UICollectionCell` so that you can scroll horizontally and vertically.

see Back image, this is how you can implemented output looked like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Tinu Dahiya pointed it correctly, You should use `tableView` and custom `tableViewCells` to achieve your `UI` design. This approach will also make your coding easy to **handle dynamic contents** which you might be fetching from server. For your reference you can directly use [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/instagram-feed-view) control from `cocoa controls`. This control is ready made dish for you, you just have to implement your logic to achieve your functionality.